# How do I also include exclamation and question mark into this code?

Tags: javascript, split

I am a beginner and I am trying to write a program that checks if a text have three sentences (or more) next to each other that starts with a "The". This code works for sentences that ends with period (".") but not with "?" or "!". How to I include this in my code so that for example "The cat! The woman? The boy." gives the same result as "The cat. The woman. The boy."?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

See if three (or more) sentences next to each other starts with "The".





<form id = "quiz" name = "quiz">

<input id = "text1" type = "text" name = "question1"> <!here you are supposed to paste the text you want to check>
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Split into sentences" onclick = "Split();">




<p id="demo"></p>






<script>
function Split() {
 question1 = document.quiz.question1.value; 
let str = question1;

const firstWords = str =>
  str .split (/\. /) .map (s => s .split (/\s+/) [0])



let result = (firstWords (str)).toString();


let x=result.lastIndexOf("The,The,The");


if (x>=0) {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'You have to many sentences next to each other that starts with "the".';}






}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for any "?.!"  `/[.?!]/`

Comment: Thank you! But I need it to work with a space after the "." "?" "!". Your solution doesn't work with "The man. The woman? The bird!" only with "The man?The woman?The bird!".

Comment: Your code is unreadable, read [ask] and more importantly how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Split on the required chars, trim and check the first words.

```js
var str = "The man. The woman?The bird! only with"

function Split(str) {

  const firstWords = str =>
    str.split(/[\.\?!]/).map(s => s.trim().split(/\s+/)[0])

  let result = (firstWords(str)).toString();
  let x = result.lastIndexOf("The,The,The");

  if (x >= 0) {
    console.log('You have to many sentences next to each other that starts with "the".');
  } else {
    console.log('You are ok.');
  }
}

Split(str);
```